# CS50 Week5 Speller error1

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote this and it doesn't compile successfully, but I don't know why.  Can you help?

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = (LENGTH+1 * 'z');

// Hash table
int total_words = 0;
node *table[N];
// [nn3, new_node2, nn4, ...]
//          |
//      new_node

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // Obtain the hash index
    int index = hash(word);

    node *cursor = table[index];
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        sum += tolower(word[i]);
    }
    return (sum % N);
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Open the dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Read strings from file one at a time
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // Create a new node
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(new_node == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // We can copy over the word to the node
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);
        new_node->next = NULL;

        // Obtain hashin index
        int index = hash(word);
        if(table[index] == NULL)
        {
            table[index] = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            new_node->next = table[index];
            table[index] = new_node;
        }
        total_words++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return total_words;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // Free the linked list
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *head = table[i];
        node *cursor = head;
        node *tmp = head;

        while(cursor != NULL)
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
            tmp = cursor;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I got every time this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [<builtin>: dictionary] Error 1
```

After a long time researching, I found nothing to fix it.  Can someone help me?

Comment: You need a `main` - otherwise, what will be run when your program is called? If you want to compile a library for use later as part of a program that will provide a main, you'll need a compiler flag like `-c`.

Comment: `undefined reference to main` seems pretty clear. All C programs require a `main` function.

Comment: regarding: `const unsigned int N = (LENGTH+1 * 'z');`  since 'z' will be evaluated as a number in this statement, with an ASCII value of: 122, the number of 'buckets' in the hash table would be (assuming LENGTH is 30) (30+1)*122 = 3782 buckets

Comment: @user3629249 — can you check where you put your parentheses?  I thought '(LENGTH + 1 * 'z')` evaluated to 152, not 3782.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, your right, thanks for catching that

Comment: How are you trying to compile it?  Are you executing `make dictionary`? That would give this error. The distro code includes a makefile, therefore one only needs to execute `make`.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to compile the file `dictionary.c` but I needed to compile `speller50`.